# PHP - Search String And Remove Element in Json

Tags: php, json

I want to search string in json and remove it, but my code doesn't work,

this example of json :

```
{
   d: {
    results: [
              {
                name: "first",
                Url: "http://example.com/tes.pdf"
              },
              {

                name: "second",
                Url: "http://example.com/download/qwdahfvajvlaksjkjdfaklfaf"
             }
           ]
   }
}
```

and this my php code :

```
$result = file_get_contents("cache.json");
$jsonObj = json_decode($result); 
foreach($jsonObj->d->results as $key => $value) { 
    if(strpos($value->Url, '.pdf') !== true) {
        unset($key->$value);
    }

}
echo json_encode($jsonObj);
```

in this case, i want to remove element **second** is not contain url ".pdf",

anyone can help me?

Comment: not a valid json check http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$result = '{"d":{"results":[{"name": "first","Url": "http://example.com/tes.pdf"},{"name": "second","Url": "http://example.com/download/qwdahfvajvlaksjkjdfaklfaf"}]}}';
$jsonArr= json_decode($result, true); //this is an array


foreach($jsonArr['d']['results'] as $key => $value) { 
    if(strpos($value['Url'], '.pdf') !== false) {
        continue; //found so not interested in it
    } else {
        unset($jsonArr['d']['results'][$key]);
    }

}
echo json_encode($jsonArr);
```

When I work with keys and values, I like to convert (if needed) it to an array. It's easier to understand and manipulate.

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: Let's try to keep the comments focused on the *technical merit* of a post, please. Since the little error has been fixed, I've deleted the comments.

Comment: @AndrewBarber thanks and to George Garchagudashvili, thank you for the input on that fix.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet would be converting it to an array, using `json_decode()`; from there, you can iterate through your array. If it stays in the same structure, then something like the following should work:

```
<?php 
    $a = $array['d']['results'];
    foreach($a as $b => $c) {
        if(strpos($c['Url'], '.pdf') !== FALSE) {
            // Found
        } else {
            unset($a[$b]); // Unset in original array.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry? Their JSON isn't valid, but I assume thats them typing it not copying it, since  the only issue is that the keys aren't made into strings.

Comment: not assume always check what OP posted if any miss suggest for correction

Comment: Also, it is worth noting; that whilst it isn't valid JSON, it does actually work. http://jsfiddle.net/yajdtenL/